# Run LLVM optimizer and compiler and execute directly from memory

Tags: llvm-ir

Let me explain my question in 4 steps:

1. LLVM is written in C++.  Can one develop a C++ program and statically link the LLVM source code of the optimizer and code generator?
2. Directly build the C++ "IR class structure" in memory (ref: https://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#important-and-useful-llvm-apis), hence, bypassing the text-based IR language and IR language interpreter.
3. Let LLVM optimize + generate execute machine code from memory, link from external libraries, and write to memory (not to a file)?
4. Directly execute the code like a JIT compiler would do?

In other words, I want to start from a memory image representing the LLVM classes, and optimize, compile and execute from memory, without any need of any intermediate files.
Could it be done?

Comment: See http://llvm.org/devmtg/2008-08/Begeman_EfficientJIT.pdf. And by the way writing to bitcode files is writing to memory